# Telegram API trouble with article Python

Tags: python, inline, telegram, telegram-bot

Good day, how i can upload image/photo on method answerInlineQuery in parameter 'article'? how it' work on @imdb bot:

[image: Example image]

Because when i send image in parameter 'message_text' it's not always loaded.

Answer (score 1):

That image from your example was grabbed from the link included in message.

You can set parse_mode=HTML and make a link to your image around unbreakable space like this:
`<a href="IMAGE">&nbsp;</a>`

Comment: Sorry it was my fault, put there just a simple space symbol. It will be the same effect.